# Continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ which is constant when $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+\pi)$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+\pi)$ all $x$ in $\mathbb R$ then $f$ is constant.

Comment: Hint: The subgroup $\mathbb{Z}+\pi\mathbb{Z}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @julien Make that an answer!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Dirichlet Theorem, the set

$$\{ m+ n \pi \mid m,n \in \mathbb Z \}$$

is dense in $\mathbb R$.

It is easy to show that $f(m+ n \pi)=f(0)$ for all $n,m \in \mathbb Z$, and using the definition of continuity and denseness mentioned above you can get that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $f$ is nonconstant. If it is nonconstant, continuous, and periodic, it must have a least positive period, $T$ (proof of this can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/440196/33383)). If $f(x) = f(x+1)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $T=1/m$, where $m$ is a positive integer. Also, if $f(x) = f(x+\pi)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $T = \pi/n$, where $n$ is a positive integer. Since it cannot be that $1/m = \pi/n$, we have a contradiction, which then implies that $f$ cannot be nonconstant.

Comment: The fact that there are two periods does not imply that they are rationally proportional.

Comment: If $1,\pi, a_2,a_3,\ldots$ be a basis of $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Define $f(1)=f(\pi)=0$  and $f(a_i)=1$. Extend by linearity. This function is non-constant and has those periods.

Comment: @julien There aren't two periods, there is one, which, by the hypothesis of the problem, is both rational and irrational. Hence the contradiction.

Comment: @Franklin.vp How can a function have more than one period?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 your mistake in the edited answer is in assuming that a function necessarily _has_ a smallest period.  Consider the function $f_{\mathbb{Q}}$ which is 1 on rationals and 0 on irrationals; then for all $n$, $f_{\mathbb{Q}}(x+\frac{1}{n}) = f_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$, so $f_{\mathbb{Q}}$ has no smallest period.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks. That's rather interesting and something I never considered. I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I added the existence of a least positive period to the answer. I think that should fix things.

Comment: It is still incomplete. You can't deduce reach a contradiction (like $T=\pi/n$) without a further argument. And this further argument is that $\mathbb{Z}+\pi \mathbb{Z}$ is dense (I can't see how to avoid that), like in N.S.'s answer. This would violate the existence of a least positive period. But it also makes the observation that there is a least positive period useless (since you can directly argue like in N.S.'s answer), although it is interesting.