# What determines if a function has a least positive period?

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

This question stems from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289451/continuous-function-on-mathbbr-which-is-constant-when-fx-fx1-fx-pi) one, where if $f$ is continuous and $f(x) = f(x+1) = f(x+\pi)$, then $f$ must be constant. The above is shown using the density of $\mathbb{Z}+\pi\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ and the continuity of $f$. However, what jumps out at me from the question is the (seeming) incongruity of a period that is both rational and irrational.

Specifically, if $f$ is non-constant and has a least positive period, $T$, then it cannot be that $f(x)=f(x+1)=f(x+\pi)$, since that would imply that $\pi$ is rational. But, as was pointed out to me, this cannot be used to prove the above because not every periodic function has a least positive period.

So my question is, what determines if a function has a least positive period? Are there certain classes of functions that, if periodic, must have a least positive period? For instance, continuous periodic functions?

Also, what other examples are there of non-constant periodic functions that do not have a least positive period? The example given to me (and the only one given on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function#cite_note-1)) is the indicator function of rational numbers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a given function $f$, consider the set $P = \{ p \in \mathbb{R} \mid \forall x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x+p) = f(x) \}$. Clearly $0 \in P$, and if $p, q \in P$ also $p - q \in P$. That means $P$ is a subgroup of the additive group of the real numbers. Several cases can arise

1. $P = \{0\}$. In that case $f$ is not periodic at all.
2. $P = p\mathbb{Z}$ for some $p > 0$. Then $p$ is the least period of $f$.
3. $P = \mathbb{R}$. This is the case for constant functions.
4. $P$ is a dense proper subgroup of $\mathbb{R}$, as in your example of the indicator function of the rationals, where $P = \mathbb{Q}$.

No other subgroups exist.
To construct an arbitrary periodic function, you can take any nontrivial
subgroup $P$ and define an arbitrary function on the quotient $\mathbb{R}/P$. This fixes the whole function, since it must be constant on every coset of $P$. 
In case 2 the quotient can be represented as the interval $[0, p)$; for case 4
this tends to be trickier, but a slightly more interesting example would be
$$
f(x) =  \begin{cases}
  p  & \text{for}\, x = q + \sqrt{p},\; q \in \mathbb{Q}, p \,\text{prime}, \\
  0  & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Great answer. +1

Comment: So if there are both rational and irrational periods, the subgroup must be of either the third or fourth type. Such a subgroup of periods of a continuous function could not be of the fourth type, so it must be of the third, which would then imply that such a function is constant.

Comment: That's correct. Functions of the fourth type are necessarily nowhere continuous.

Comment: Thanks. This is very cool.

Comment: Sorry for the bump,  but are there known specific hypotheses on $f$ that grant 2. to hold?

Comment: @GabrielR.: Well, from the above you can get a reasonable sufficient condition: if a $f$ is not constant, is continuous at some point and has at least one period, that rules out cases 1, 3 and 4.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Why does  continuity at one given point rule out 4? I can get it when it is continous everywhere.

Comment: @GabrielR.: Because the subgroup is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and so are all its cosets. That means the function takes the same range of values in every neighbourhood of every point.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are very good.  Here is a 1915 theorem of Burstin that also seems relevant:

> If a Lebesgue measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has arbitrarily small periods, then $f$ is constant almost everywhere.

A nice proof is given in [this one page MONTHLY note of J.M. Henle](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Henle80.pdf).  A comment at the bottom claims that Burstin's original proof was faulty.

Comment: When should I expect a response?

Comment: Let me remark that Burstin's proof was incorrect. This theorem was discovered independently by Łomnicki: A. Łomnicki, O wielookresowych funkcjach jednoznacznych zmiennej rzeczywistej, Sprawozdania z Posiedzeń Towarzystwa Naukowego Warszawskiego, Wydział III Nauk Matematycznych i Przyrodniczych 11 (1918), 807–846.

and sometimes it is called the Burstin–Łomnicki theorem.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that a nonconstant continuous periodic function must have a least positive period. First, if there are periods arbitarily close to zero, then pick your favorite point $x$ and value $f(z)$. Since the periods are getting smaller and smaller, there must be a sequence of $z_n \rightarrow x$ with $f(z_i) = f(z)$ for all $i$. Hence $f(z) = f(x)$ by continuity, violating that $f$ is nonconstant. So there is some positive lower bound $L$ to the set of periods.

If there is a sequence of periods $p_i \neq L$ converging to $L$, then $f(x + L) = f(x) = f(x + L + p_i)$ and so we have a sequence of periods converging to zero. So $L$ must be a period.